# Apache Cassandra 3.7 snitch issue cannot start data center

Tags: cassandra

I am using ubuntu 14.04 with apache cassandra 3.7. I am trying to start it but get the following error message:

> ERROR [main] 2016-07-15 15:22:10,627 CassandraDaemon.java:731 - Cannot start node if snitch's data center (dc1) differs from previous data center (datacenter1). Please fix the snitch configuration, decommission and rebootstrap this node or use the flag -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true.

I know I can set `-Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true`, BUT that is not a fix, its a band-aid and for development use only, this is suppose to be in production. I tried to clear out all the files and folders in */var/lib/cassandra*, I MEAN every SINGLE FILE AND FOLDER, started apache cassandra again, AND STILL THE SAME ERROR MESSAGE... any other idea??

Comment: Have you modified the cassandra.yaml/cassandra-env.sh files?

Answer (score 1):

change in file:
/etc/cassandra/cassandra-rackdc.properties
entry from dc1 to datacenter1 
on all nodes
and then do a rolling restart of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If have just switched to GossipingPropertyFileSnitch, start Cassandra with the option

```
-Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true
```

If it starts successfully, execute:

```
nodetool repair
nodetool cleanup
```

Afterwards, Cassandra should be able to start normally without the ignore option.

Comment: where do you add the option `-Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true` ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue while upgrading my Apache cassandra from 3.11.1 to 3.11.4 .
        cassandra.yaml

old_Config :  endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch

New_Config:   endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch

{changed it to GossipingPropertyFileSnitch}

cassandra-rackdc.properties

old_version_config: dc:Dc1  rack:Rack1

New_version_config: dc:dc   rack:rack (changed this to Dc1 and Rack1)

this resolves my issue